# I don't get any log in the console when I run ng s

Tags: json, angular

I wanna create a dynamic form using angular. I am currently using Angular CLI 15.2.2 and node 18.15.0 .
I have defined the method NgOnInit and have included HttpClient in the components.ts file.

This is the json file for the registration form...

```
[
    {
        "ID":"FirstName",
        "Label":"First Name",
        "Type":"input",
        "Value":""
    },{
        "ID":"LastName",
        "Label":"Last Name",
        "Type":"input",
        "Value":""
    },{
        "ID":"MobileNo",
        "Label":"Mobile No",
        "Type":"input",
        "Value":""
    },{
        "ID":"EmailId",
        "Label":"Email Id",
        "Type":"input",
        "Value":""
    },{
        "ID":"Gender",
        "Label":"Gender",
        "Type":"radio",
        "Value":"Male,Female"
    },{
        "ID":"DOB",
        "Label":"DOB",
        "Type":"date",
        "Value":""
    },{
        "ID":"Address",
        "Label":"Address",
        "Type":"input",
        "Value":""
    },{
        "ID":"City",
        "Label":"City",
        "Type":"select",
        "Value":"Mumbai,Delhi,Chennai"
    },{
        "ID":"State",
        "Label":"State",
        "Type":"select",
        "Value":"Maharastra,Delhi,TamilNadu"
    },{
        "ID":"Pincode",
        "Label":"Pincode",
        "Type":"input",
        "Value":""
    }
]
```

And this is the app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RegistrationformComponent } from './registrationform/registrationform.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegistrationformComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and this is the registrationform.components.ts file,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registrationform',
  templateUrl: './registrationform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registrationform.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationformComponent implements OnInit{

  dynamicFormArray: any;
  
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){

  }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.httpClient.get('/assets/DynamicFormControl.json').subscribe(data => {
      this.dynamicFormArray = data;
      console.log(this.dynamicFormArray);
    })
  }
}
```

Even though theres a console.log() in the method OnInit, i dont see a log in chrome when ng serve is run

Comment: Most likely the http request goes in error and you are not catching it. Do you see any error in the console tab?

Comment: See your network tab if endpoint is working or not? Let me know if you are not able to see any log, I mean not only the endpoint's response.

Comment: There was nothing being displayed in console. Surprisingly, the same code worked when I installed node version 19.7.0 and angular version 15.2.2 (latest).